# Laravel CSS and Bootstrap doesn't working

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I created a new Laravel project and downloaded the bootstrap CSS and JS files and put the CSS file in resources/css and the JS files of bootstrap and popper and jQuery in resources/js and in the welcome.blade.php I linked the CSS file and the JS files like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Osama The Coder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="text-danger">
        Hello World
    </section>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

when I opened the project it was just the text without any styles or Bootstrap font-family
even when I linked the app.css and applied color red to the section element I doesn't see any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the following steps

1. Put all your static assets in public directory
2. Organize your assets in different folders e.g public/js for js related files and public/css for css related files
3. Then access your files using the helper method like below

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
   /* or js files */
   <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
   ```

Comment: it worked fine but can you explain why it isn't worked in the previous?

Comment: This is basically due to the HOST_URL. HOST_URL is where our main root index.php file is located. By default, it is placed inside the public/index.php file therefor our HOST_URL becomes http://localhost:8000/public but according to the rules set inside .htaccess file we don't need to use /public because it is ignore so we can use http://localhost:8000/ to access public directory directly. If you print the {{asset('')}} , then you will get the same HOST_URL without the public. Henceforth, we can easily target all files inside the public directory with asset helper method